# How popular are anti-mimetic theories of literature, and with whom?

Tags: structuralism, literary-theory, art, modernism

How popular are anti-mimetic theories of literature, and with whom?

A bad but clear example of supposed mimesis, in writing, is the idea that 'cow' is a slow and irritating word, because of its phonemes.

Specifically, should it be limited to modernists overawed by Saussure? I'm especially interested in answers that draw on the Russian Formalists.

---

And ideally, Jakobson.

Having not read him, I can't make sense of whether his definition of *poetic language*, "the projection of the principle of equivalence from the axis of selection to the axis of combination", does, or does not, displace sound from meaning. I think at least "most" lit theorists think so, but can't quite see how. Given that formalist criticism is not itself ***closed*** but can offer criticism of principles of composition -- and so 'equivalence'.

A little speculative thought that, perhaps.

Comment: Anti-mimesis is usually associated with modernists and postmodernists, see [Rethinking Mimesis](http://www.cambridgescholars.com/download/sample/60256):"*Despite  some  modern  and 
postmodern trends that dismissed the questions of representation from the theory of art in favour of language-games or purely formal considerations of some other kind, the interest in artistic and literary representation has not diminished*". See also Cohen's book Anti-Mimesis. But interestingly, Adorno, in many ways a forerunner of postmodernism, is known for his view of art as "*refuge for mimetic behavior*".

Comment: @Conifold the cohen book looks fun! but not sure i've used the term 'mimesis' right, now.